# How to connect monkeytalk app to the IDE

Tags: ios, ide, monkeytalk

I build a GUI application integrated with MonkeyTalk (from Gorilla Logic), through the agent library.

In the IDE, I could create the .mt file also.

But, I donno, how to connect the monkey talk app, to the monkeytalk IDE.

Can anyone suggest **how to connect the monkeytalk app to the IDE?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it is not clear what you trying to say. please provide more info what are the steps you followed and what are the errors or results you got for each.

I think you missed connection step look here https://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-getting-started/connect-your-app .

If not worked. start over There is a very clear documentation about setup process in gorilla logic site. https://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-getting-started/install-ide

please follow each step very carefully definitely you will succeed.

Comment: The issue is, unlike 'monkeytest' in android, where the GUI events are randomly executed by itself; I find it difficult to write the GUI execution sequence ourself in the script. Since the events are not auto-generated, there is only very little chance exists to find out any issue in GUI.

Comment: Yea, Try out Calabash it works great for me. it has ruby console where you can query and see the current GUI components in the device screen.